# Fb no longer allow underscore in domain names using Fb.Share?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB.ui to send user to his wall.

Up until a few weeks ago all was ok but now half of my shares stopped working.

Here is my code:

```
FB.ui({
     method:'feed',
     app_id:677888332222437,
     link:'http://mozilla_firefox.en.downloadastro.com',
     picture:'http://images.downloadastro.com/icon/mozilla_firefox_64_64.jpeg',
     name:'Mozilla Firefox',
     caption:'Great software - pass it on',
     description:'User-friendly and personalized internet browser'},
     function(response){if(response&&response.post_id){self.location.href='//mozilla_firefox.en.downloadastro.com/download/'}
else{self.location.href='//mozilla_firefox.en.downloadastro.com/download/'}});
}
```

Now what I have found using FB developer dashboard, is that if I change the URL from "http://mozilla_firefox.en.downloadastro.com" to "http://mozilla-firefox.en.downloadastro.com" it works, so the problem is in the underscore.

But have anybody seen this errors? How can I override this?

Comment: All you can do is file a bug report with Facebook and ask them to fix it.

Comment: I did, but the question is, is there any workaround? Right now I am only thinking about a rewrite rules that will fix this.

Comment: If Facebook is not willing to fix their URL/domain parser – then no.